# sshd in Ubuntu 16.04 - login takes very long

Tags: ssh, login, 16.04

I've seen ssh logins take some seconds many times before in the past. I always found that inappropriate. After I reinstalled my workstations with Xubuntu 16.04, this effect became really disruptive. Between two workstations in the same LAN, it takes more than 10 seconds for an ssh login. Afterwards, everything is fast.

The machines can find each other via dns in no time via my router. However, I also tried `UseDNS no`. I also tried `GSSAPIAuthentication no` as found on the web. Both had no effect.

I authenticate via public key.

This is a snippet of debug output from the ssh client:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/pino/.ssh/ids/heisterkamp/22/pino
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to heisterkamp ([fd00::8d93:c17b:595a:347f]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
```

Now the thing is 'sleeping' for the 10 seconds. Afterwards, it continues this way:

```
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0.0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IPV6_TCLASS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
...
```

Does anyone see what is the reason for the waiting time?

Edit: There are some more details worth mentioning:

- When I use my workstations to login to some other Debian machines in the same network, it takes just a second.
- I've configured pam_mount to mount a luks-encrypted volume on login. However, in my situation, this volume is already mounted. And mounting should, even if unmounted, should just take about 3 seconds.

Comment: I also have a similar issue on 16.04 (between a VirtualBox VM guest running RHEL 7.1 and the host machine connected by a custom WiFi network defined on the host); but the delay is intermittent, and it always appears between the first pair of occurrences of `debug3: send packet: type 50` and the corresponding `receive` (`debug3: receive packet: type 51`) (although more `type 50` packets are sent later on, they get instant replies).

Answer (score 4):

Same problem. 
Notice I can see after the 10 seconds delay a: "*Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.login1': timed out*" in auth.log

Solution:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Found it [here](https://serverfault.com/a/742102)

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue with hanging at "debug1: pledge: exec" in my case:

```
apt install --reinstall systemd
```